# Construction of free resolution of modules over a group ring.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm reading [this](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=JTNB_2000__12_1_219_0) paper, it says(in Theoerm 2) that:

> Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, $G$ a finite group, $\Delta G$ the augmentation ideal of the integral group ring $\mathbb Z G$ and a $G$-modules extension $A\hookrightarrow B \twoheadrightarrow \Delta G$, then taking a free resolution of $B$ we get a commutative diagram (4) below:

[image]

> How is $\mathbb Z G^{m}$ constructed that maps correspondingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}G^m$ is the direct sum of $m$ copies of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$.  The map $\mathbb{Z}G^m\twoheadrightarrow\Delta G$ is just mapping $1$ in each summand to corresponding generators of the ideal and extend by $\mathbb{Z}G$-linearity.

Comment: $m$ copies of $\mathbb Z G$ or $G$($= (\mathbb Z G)^{m}$ or $\mathbb Z (G^{m})$)? How does it map to $B$?

Comment: @CYC The context is that $\mathbb{Z}G^m=(\mathbb{Z}G)^m$ because we are dealing with a **free** resolution of $B$. Free modules over $\mathbb{Z}G$ are precisely $(\mathbb{Z}G)^m$. This also shows where the $\mathbb{Z}G^m\to B$ mapping comes from (the free resolution).